# How to calculate digestvalue for XML in php with enveloped-signature

Tags: php, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

I am trying to calculate digest value for an digitally signed XML, but I am not able to match the digest value mentioned in DigestValue tag.

I am trying to validate XML signature in PHP.
First part of the validation is to check digest. 
I am using following code to do the digest calculation.

```
<?php
$xml_str ='<Receipt Version="1.0" ReceiptDate="2012-08-30T23:08:52Z" CertificateId="b809e47cd0110a4db043b3f73e83acd917fe1336" ReceiptDeviceId="4e362949-acc3-fe3a-e71b-89893eb4f528">
    <ProductReceipt Id="6bbf4366-6fb2-8be8-7947-92fd5f683530" ProductId="Product1" PurchaseDate="2012-08-30T23:08:52Z" ExpirationDate="2012-09-02T23:08:49Z" ProductType="Durable" AppId="55428GreenlakeApps.CurrentAppSimulatorEventTest_z7q3q7z11crfr" />
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>Uvi8jkTYd3HtpMmAMpOm94fLeqmcQ2KCrV1XmSuY1xI=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>TT5fDET1X9nBk9/yKEJAjVASKjall3gw8u9N5Uizx4/Le9RtJtv+E9XSMjrOXK/TDicidIPLBjTbcZylYZdGPkMvAIc3/1mdLMZYJc+EXG9IsE9L74LmJ0OqGH5WjGK/UexAXxVBWDtBbDI2JLOaBevYsyy+4hLOcTXDSUA4tXwPa2Bi+BRoUTdYE2mFW7ytOJNEs3jTiHrCK6JRvTyU9lGkNDMNx9loIr+mRks+BSf70KxPtE9XCpCvXyWa/Q1JaIyZI7llCH45Dn4SKFn6L/JBw8G8xSTrZ3sBYBKOnUDbSCfc8ucQX97EyivSPURvTyImmjpsXDm2LBaEgAMADg==</SignatureValue>
    </Signature>
</Receipt>';

if( !$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml_str ) )
{
    echo 'Unable to load XML string<br />';
}
else
{
    print 'XML String loaded successfully<br />';
}


$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://lic.apps.microsoft.com/licensing/certificateserver/?cid=".$xml["CertificateId"]);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$responseFromServer = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
echo '<br/>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>';
echo $responseFromServer;
echo '<br/>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>';
$signature     = $xml->Signature->SignatureValue;
//echo $data;
$key = openssl_get_publickey($responseFromServer);
$signature_decoded = base64_encode(pack("H*",$signature));

$signatureInfo1=' <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>Uvi8jkTYd3HtpMmAMpOm94fLeqmcQ2KCrV1XmSuY1xI=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>TT5fDET1X9nBk9/yKEJAjVASKjall3gw8u9N5Uizx4/Le9RtJtv+E9XSMjrOXK/TDicidIPLBjTbcZylYZdGPkMvAIc3/1mdLMZYJc+EXG9IsE9L74LmJ0OqGH5WjGK/UexAXxVBWDtBbDI2JLOaBevYsyy+4hLOcTXDSUA4tXwPa2Bi+BRoUTdYE2mFW7ytOJNEs3jTiHrCK6JRvTyU9lGkNDMNx9loIr+mRks+BSf70KxPtE9XCpCvXyWa/Q1JaIyZI7llCH45Dn4SKFn6L/JBw8G8xSTrZ3sBYBKOnUDbSCfc8ucQX97EyivSPURvTyImmjpsXDm2LBaEgAMADg==</SignatureValue>
    </Signature>';
$signatureInfo2=' <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>Uvi8jkTYd3HtpMmAMpOm94fLeqmcQ2KCrV1XmSuY1xI=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>';
$signatureInfo3='
           <Receipt Version="1.0" ReceiptDate="2012-08-30T23:08:52Z" CertificateId="b809e47cd0110a4db043b3f73e83acd917fe1336" ReceiptDeviceId="4e362949-acc3-fe3a-e71b-89893eb4f528">
    <ProductReceipt Id="6bbf4366-6fb2-8be8-7947-92fd5f683530" ProductId="Product1" PurchaseDate="2012-08-30T23:08:52Z" ExpirationDate="2012-09-02T23:08:49Z" ProductType="Durable" AppId="55428GreenlakeApps.CurrentAppSimulatorEventTest_z7q3q7z11crfr" />

</Receipt>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($signatureInfo3);
$canonicalized = $dom->C14N(TRUE, FALSE);
$digest = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $canonicalized,TRUE));
echo '<br/>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>';
echo $digest;
echo '<br/>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>';
?>
```

I have tried all the variations, but not able to match Uvi8jkTYd3HtpMmAMpOm94fLeqmcQ2KCrV1XmSuY1xI= this.
Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what `signatureInfo1` and the similar variables are doing here. Could you maybe add the workflow of your script in the question?

Comment: `How to calculate digestvalue for XML in php` doesn't make much sense. Instead of dumping the whole code, can you isolate your issue further?  It's unclear what you're asking, TBH.